# OpenLayers features correctly display, but reset on layer redraw (zoom in/out e.g.)

Tags: openlayers

I'm retrieving Latitude/Longitude and elementID fields from some items on  an SQL DB and displaying the data on an OpenLayer map.
Everything works fine except this: when I zoom in or out, each feature maintains the correct position, but the labels showing the `elementid` all reset to the last processed value. I mean that if the last element retrieved from the DB has an `elementid` equal to *455*, every feature on the map shows a label of *455*.

Why this happens? 
I worked with a similar code on GMaps some months ago and had not this problem.

Here's the code I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/257xj00j/5/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Turn your example into a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to make it easier to analyse it. Also, since you're already importing jQuery you can replace your `downloadUrl` function with `$.ajax`.

Comment: I did my homeworks :) 
Learned how to use JSFiddle and learned about the $.ajax call.
It now works, but the problem remains.  Any idea? Thanks kryger.